# Can't instantiate Python class even though it's being imported

Tags: python

I'm writing a Python package that looks like this:

```
|- datum/
    |- __init__.py
    |- database.py
```

**__init__.py**

```
from .database import Database

def connect(url):
    print(Database)         # for debugging
    return Database(url)
```

**database.py**

```
class Database(object):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url

    ...more methods
```

This is installed as a package called `datum` in development mode. If I call `connect` outside of this package like:

```
import datum
db = datum.connect('postgresql://xxx')
```

...this is the output:

```
<class 'datum.database.Database'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Z:\AIS\Flask\ais\engine\scripts\load_pwd_parcels.py", line 30, in <module>
    source_db = Database(source_db_url)
NameError: name 'Database' is not defined
```

I'm confused because the class is being imported fine -- I can print it and even run `dir` on it and see all my methods -- but when I try to instantiate something it's "not defined". Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Where is `load_pwd_parcels.py` stored relative to your `datum` directory?

Comment: It's in a separate package (a Flask application).

Comment: Are you sure you are importing a version of `datum` that has a `Database` class? There's not enough information in your question to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning away all of the old .pyc files?

Answer (score 0):

A [`NameError`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.NameError) means that a local or global name cannot be found.  I would make sure that your "load_pwd_parcels.py" file includes:

```
from database import Database
```

Alternatively, you could do:

```
import database
source_db = database.Database(source_db_url)
```

The latter option is a great choice because it gives `database` its very own namespace.  In the words of Tim Peters in [PEP 20 -- The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/):
"Namespaces are one honking great idea - let's do more of those!"